# Problems with Zbar (ZbarSymbolSet) and Xcode8

Tags: ios10, xcode8, zbar

I'm having difficulty with the use of ZBar library as soon as I opened the project in Swift 2.2 with Xcode 8. I've always used a bridge to run this library but on xcode I immediately a red extension of ZbarSymbolSet.
`Use of undeclared type 'ZbarSymbolSet'`

```
//Extension for Zbar
extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 3:

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // ADD: get the decode results
        let results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as! NSFastEnumeration

        var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

        for symbol in results as! ZBarSymbolSet {
            symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
            break
        }
        let resultString = symbolFound!.data
        print(resultString)
    }
```